# increased a varchar size in whole mysql db at once

Tags: mysql, django

I know we can increased the size of varchar using this command:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME modify COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL;
```

Suppose I have 10 tables and each table has one common column which is varchar and its name is "title". Is there any query which I can execute regardless of table names and it will update the size of this field in each and every table?

Scenario:

Actually I have used a `BaseModel` which is `Abstract` and many of my models inherit themselves from that. Now I have Update the title length to 500 in my Base Model. Doing a Manage.py syncdb will not going to reflect these changes. So that is why I need above query.

```
class TitleAndSlugModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="The part of the title that is used in the url")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it via SQL directly... instead,  change it in all your models (e.g.  max_length=1024) and do a migration using South -->  http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/tutorial/part1.html

South == awsomeness

also, you might need to convert your app to use South --> http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app

etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, but really it's not very hard to do if it's only 10 or so tables.

```
#!/bin/bash
{
  echo "USE some_database;"
  for table in TABLE1 TABLE2 ...
  do
    echo "alter table `$table` modify COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL;"
  done
} | mysql -h ... -u ... -p ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use information_schema to dump the DDL statements into a SQL script, and then source the script to execute it. Assuming you don't have any charset, collation, or other overrides on your columns you could do something like this:

```
-- alter all varchar columns named title to be varchar(1024)
select concat('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,
' MODIFY COLUMN ',column_name,' VARCHAR(1024)',
if(IS_NULLABLE='YES',' NULL',' NOT NULL'),';"') as the_ddl 
into outfile '/tmp/modify_title_columns.sql'
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = '<your_schema>' 
and column_name = 'title'
and data_type = 'varchar';

\. /tmp/modify_title_columns.sql
```